# Geting ERROR: Config value cuda is not defined in any .rc file when trying to train mobilenet in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tf-slim

I'm trying to run `MobileNet_v1` on `ImageNet` and for that I'm using the [official Tensorflow Model repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.md) and following their guide.
However when I actually tried to run the training for `MobileNet_v1` by first initiating :

```
models/research/slim$ bazel build -c opt --config=cuda mobilenet_v1_{eval,train}
```

I got :

```
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=146
ERROR: Config value cuda is not defined in any .rc file
```

All previous steps have been successful and everything seems fine except this one.
I'm using :

```
Ubuntu 16.04  
TF version: v1.7.0 (and 1.10.1) 
Cuda v9.0  
cuDNN v7.0 (and 7.1.3)  
bazel release 0.16.1
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the [bazel releases page](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases),

> --[no]allow_undefined_configs no longer exists, passing undefined
>   configs is an error.

as of version 0.16.0 and above.

Using an older version of bazel should solve your problem for now.

Comment: Add a hint for coming people who just found this answer. Currently, the .deb on the official site no longer provides old version. the old version can get from here https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tags?after=0.19.0